Displaying Images from DO Spaces to Template
Is there a way to recursively call images from a digital ocean spaces bucket folder into a twig template (similar to how locally stored images work)? Or would I have to build a module to do that?

There's a plugin that adds Digital Ocean Spaces as a Filesystem Type. After installation, you can create a new filesystem using the newly added filesystem type, and an asset volume that uses this filesystem. After that, you can upload and manage assets that live on the Digital Ocean Space through Craft's normal asset interface. Then you can also query assets on your Digital Ocean Space like you would a volume using the local filesystem.

I'm realizing that my issue is actually stemming from the fact that my issue was due to multiple errors. My images were being added into dynamic subfolders i.e. {slug} and I didn't have a public URL. Fixed those thanks to those links you've provided. Thank you!
